# How To Mix Set Terms With Random Elements

Tags: r

I would like to generate a random set of coordinates within a certain range and then print the results in the form of hours, minutes, seconds (e.g. 39° 50' 30" N).

What I have so far:

```
#Set the seed for random number generation
set.seed(0112)

#Define the integers for each part of the coordinates
h <- sample.int(38:41, 1)
m <- sample.int(52, 1)
s <- sample.int(31, 1)

#Print the results
print(paste("h","°","m","'","s", "", "N"), quote = FALSE)
```

Which results in:

```
##[1] h ° m ' s  N
```

How do I get the numbers I've generated to show up in the print results rather than the name that I've given the integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove them from quotes (`""`) in `paste`

```
paste(h,"°",m,"'",s, "", "N")
#[1] "15 ° 48 ' 31  N"
```

---

The purpose of `quote` in `print` is different. From `?print`

> quote  - logical, indicating whether or not strings should be printed with surrounding quotes.

See for example

```
print(paste(h,"°",m,"'",s, "", "N"), quote = TRUE)
#[1] "15 ° 48 ' 31  N"

print(paste(h,"°",m,"'",s, "", "N"), quote = FALSE)
#[1] 15 ° 48 ' 31  N
```

Notice how output is surrounded by quotes (`"`) in first case and not in second case.

Comment: Thank you. ```print(paste(h,"°",m,"'",s, '"',"N"), quote = FALSE)``` gives me what I need. The single quotes force the double quote to appear next to the seconds. Any idea how to remove the whitespace between the integer and the degree symbol?

Comment: @TravisHamon use `paste0` ? `print(paste0(h,"°",m,"'",s, '"',"N"), quote = FALSE)`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Than you again